# Backbone Marionetter ItemView render event does not act with triggers and listenTo

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, render, marionette

I am developing Rails Api based on backbone.Marionette and tried to execute jquery code when the itemview rendered. 
Here is my code.

```
class Step1.Layout extends App.Views.ItemView
        template: "wizard/step1/layout"

        triggers:
            "render": "jquery:datetimepicker:runnable"
            "click .glyphicon-calendar" : "jquery:datetimepicker:runnable" ## For Test
```

And this is the Controller part.

```
Step1.Controller = 

        display: ->
            view = @getStepView()

            view.on "jquery:datetimepicker:runnable", ->
                $('#due_date').datetimepicker format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'

            App.mainRegion.show view

        getStepView: ->
            new Step1.Layout
```

So, the "click .glyphicon-calendar" acts well, but "render" does not invoke event listener in controller at all. 
I guess it's because of that the event cannot be triggered before real view exist, but not sure. 
Please notice I hope to know how to execute the jquery code when the itemView rendered, so please let me know the solution of it.

Comment: Please show the code for `@getStepView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going with the spirit of `@k2ndlab` Answer, all you'd have to do is change your `controller` code slightly, as follows:

```
Step1.Controller = 
    display: ->
        view = @getStepView()

        view.on "attach", -> // Listen to when this view's parent Region triggers 'attach'
            $('#due_date').datetimepicker format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'

        App.mainRegion.show view
```

The fact is that `triggers` are used to translate DOM interactions with the view into view events, but not to translate view events into other events, as explained in the [docs](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.2/marionette.view.html#viewtriggers). That's why doing

```
triggers:
    "attach": "jquery:datetimepicker:runnable"
```

would not work for you, since `triggers` is not listening for view events. And in your case, you just want to know when the view is in the DOM and ready to interact with jQuery, which is what listening to the `'attach'` event is for.

Incidentally, using the `onAttach` event like `@k2ndlab` suggested, ie,

```
class Step1.Layout extends App.Views.ItemView
    template: "wizard/step1/layout"

    onAttach: ->
        this.trigger 'jquery:datetimepicker:runnable'
```

would also work. But again, this is a little contrived, since all your really care for is the `'attach'` event.

Comment: Really Great Answer!!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use attach event instead of render, if you are using latest version of Marionette. Render means that your html is generated, but it does not mean that it is already in the DOM. On the other hand,  on attach event is fired when your view is in the DOM. The datetimepicker plugin might require the view to be attached to the DOM.

Take a look at this 2 links :

- http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.2/marionette.layoutview.html#use-of-the-attach-event
- http://benmccormick.org/2015/01/05/marionette-view-life-cycles/

Comment: Unfortunately, attach event does not act at all. ;(

Comment: @SamuelJansson try to manually trigger the event in onRender or onAttach callback : this.trigger('jquery:datetimepicker:runnable');